# Is there a way to delete the text in a DXL layout column?

Tags: ibm-doors

I basically just want to delete the text in the layout column and add new text. I know it's easy for existing columns (it would just be something like obj."Attribute 1" = "") but I'm having trouble referencing the DXL layout column and getting it to delete it. Here's a couple things I've tried with no luck:

```
Column disp = currentColumn
// filter through objects
void obj."disp"

display ""

null display
```

Answer (score 0):

The essence of a DXL layout column is that its value is calculated. And it's being recalculated quite often. The only way to influence the content of a DXL layout column is to edit the calculating code, the displayed value cannot be changed "from the outside".

I.e. right-click on the column header and open Properties -> Layout DXL -> Browse -> Current, and edit the code as you want it to be have, depending on your requirements, perhaps like this:

```
int absNum = obj."Absolute Number"

string s = "Hello " absNum "!"
if (absNum == 1 ) {
   s = null
}
display s
```

Comment: I tried that, but it does not delete the text in the layout column. For instance, in your example (if the layout cell previously contained "12345") the value remained "12345". Does DXL not allow me to delete text once I have already displayed it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "clear" option, at least none that I am aware of.
Every "display" command creates a NEW line and adds to the already displayed content.

That's why generally you should not have "display" commands in the middle of the code but prepare a string variable and only at the end of the code display its content

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the column header and open Properties -> Layout DXL -> Browse -> Current
and delete all code. Click OK. You will get blank layout dxl column. Is that what you want?